# How do I set up an engine never to resign in Arena GUI?

Tags: engines, arena

Is there a way to set up the engine in a way it never resignes?

I want to practice mating with bishop and knight but after the engine reaches the depth it can tell it will be checkmated it resigns. I would like to suppress that.

Comment: For your particular problem you could try playing against a tablebase. https://syzygy-tables.info/

Comment: Are you using Fritz software or something

Comment: What do you mean with "gives up"?

Comment: @David I mean "resign".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up Stockfish in a way it never gives up?

Stockfish is an engine, not a GUI. Engines never give up they just calculate the best move in any given position. GUIs can be set to give up at a certain point but not engines. You need to find out how to set the options in your GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I do not think it is completely true. In engine vs. engine games the engines do resign I guess (Stockfish vs. Leela Zero). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAQ9UJ_9lP0)'s an example. I also think that the Stockfish 15 (which I use) is set up this way.

Comment: @Jagger Again, the engines do not resign, there isn't even a way to communicate a resignation via the UCI interface. Youtubers like to anthropomorphize engines, what happened there was the old TCEC resign rule (coded into the TCEC gui) that ends the game once both engines say +10 and assigns the victor.

Answer (score 10):

I found the following [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/a7rthl/how_do_i_turn_off_resignation_from_the_computer/) on the topic.

> Engines > Manage > UCI Tab > Untick Resign box.

It is to be found here.

[image: Engine management]

Answer (score 2):

Go to lichess.org/editor , arrange the board as you like, press "continue from here",  choose Stockfish level 8, and select what color you want to play as.

Also, once you finish the game, you can press the microscope icon, hit "Toggle local evaluation", and you'll be able to go back to any move and replay from there; the engine will tell you what it would have done (you'll have to manually make the move for it, though). It will also tell you what you should do, so if you want to have practice deciding what to do, make sure to decide what you'll do before making the computer's move.